# How to do this aggregation in Python

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON response as follows.

```
{
"2015-03-08": {
"www.ndtv.com": [
{
"traffic": 100,
"name": "Server1"
}
],
"www.profit.ndtv.com": [
{
"traffic": 49.69,
"name": "Server1"
},
{
"traffic": 50.31,
"name": "Server2"
}
]
},
"2015-03-03": {
"www.ndtv.com": [
{
"traffic": 100,
"name": "Server1"
}
],
"www.profit.ndtv.com": [
{
"traffic": 50.11,
"name": "Server1"
},
{
"traffic": 49.89,
"name": "Server2"
},
{
"traffic": 0,
"name": "Server3"
}
]
},
"2015-03-05": {
"www.ndtv.com": [
{
"traffic": 100,
"name": "Server1"
}
],
"www.profit.ndtv.com": [
{
"traffic": 50.36,
"name": "Server1"
},
{
"traffic": 49.64,
"name": "Server2"
}
]
},
"2015-03-04": {
"www.ndtv.com": [
{
"traffic": 100,
"name": "Server1"
}
],
"www.profit.ndtv.com": [
{
"traffic": 50.79,
"name": "Server1"
},
{
traffic: 49.21,
name: "Server2"
}
]
},
"2015-03-07": {
"www.ndtv.com": [
{
"traffic": 100,
"name": "Server1"
}
],
"www.profit.ndtv.com": [
{
"traffic": 51.48,
"name": "Server1"
},
{
"traffic": 48.52,
"name": "Server2"
}
]
},
2015-03-06: {
"www.ndtv.com": [ ],
"www.profit.ndtv.com": [
{
"traffic": 50.96,
"name": "Server1"
},
{
"traffic": 49.04,
"name": "Server2"
}
]
}
}
```

I need to aggregate data over days. For instance for `2015-03-08` I would like to add all the traffic for Server1 , so in my example it would be `(100+49.69)/2`. I divide it by 2 as # of server1 is 2 and store it for the parent domain. In this case the output would be.

```
{
2015-03-08: {
www.ndtv.com: [
{
traffic: 74.85,
name: "Server1"
},
{
traffic: 50.31,
name: "Server2"
}
]
}
```

I am confused how to do this in Python.

Comment: It would help if your JSON was correct -- it's seriously wrong, as the keys are **not** quoted; so, Python's `json` module cannot load it.  Can you fix the source of that very-broken Json, or do you need to hack a fix...?

Comment: I would need to hack a fix here as I do not have the source to modify the JSON response.

Comment: Added the right JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added: OP now edited the Q to show correct JSON but implies the pseudo-JSON he actually deals with is the broken one -- with unquoted keys -- he had before; so I'm leaving the start of the A alone as it might help him deal with actually broken json.

First of all, you need a hack to fix that badly-broken JSON you're showing -- the keys are not quoted!  They must be, by the JSON standard (and for Python's `json` module to be able to load the JSON into a Python data structure).  Fortunately, if the example you show is normative, the breakage is quite systematic, and can be fixed.

Assuming `x` is the string you show:

```
import re, json

z = re.sub(r'([^:\s]+):', r'"\1":', x)
y = json.loads(z)
```

and now in `y` you have the needed data structure.

So now your task is easier (depending on your exact specs -- e.g I'm going to assume the *shortest* domain in the sub-dict for each day is the one you want to aggregate on, and order of servers does not matter -- these are all guesses of course, you need to be much more precise explaining your specs:-).

With these guesses...:

```
import collections

res = {}
for d in y:
    dd = y[d]
    dom = min(dd, key=len)
    res[d] = {dom: []}
    serv_traf = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for subdom in dd:
        for ddd in dd[subdom]:
            serv_traf[ddd['name']].append(ddd['traffic'])
    for serv in serv_traf:
        traf = serv_traf[serv]
        restraf = sum(traf) / len(traf)
        res[d][dom].append({'name': serv, 'traffic': restraf})
```

should do what you want.  For example, for your example broken `x`,

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint(res)
```

shows:

```
{'2015-03-03': {'www.ndtv.com': [{'name': 'Server1', 'traffic': 75.055},
                                 {'name': 'Server2', 'traffic': 49.89},
                                 {'name': 'Server3', 'traffic': 0}]},
 '2015-03-04': {'www.ndtv.com': [{'name': 'Server1', 'traffic': 75.395},
                                 {'name': 'Server2', 'traffic': 49.21}]},
 '2015-03-05': {'www.ndtv.com': [{'name': 'Server1', 'traffic': 75.18},
                                 {'name': 'Server2', 'traffic': 49.64}]},
 '2015-03-06': {'www.ndtv.com': [{'name': 'Server1', 'traffic': 50.96},
                                 {'name': 'Server2', 'traffic': 49.04}]},
 '2015-03-07': {'www.ndtv.com': [{'name': 'Server1', 'traffic': 75.74},
                                 {'name': 'Server2', 'traffic': 48.52}]},
 '2015-03-08': {'www.ndtv.com': [{'name': 'Server1', 'traffic': 74.845},
                                 {'name': 'Server2', 'traffic': 50.31}]}}
```

which appears to be at least an approximation of what you had in mind.

To turn it back into JSON, of course, you'd use `json.dumps(res)` -- which inevitably would give you **correct** JSON... hope you don't need to break it again to emulate the broken kind you started with?